# Blender (2.9) can't rotate or scale any objects in object mode using keyboard

Tags: scale

I've been working on a project in blender for a while now, and one day I open my file and suddenly It's not letting me scale or rotate objects using hotkeys.  I am able to scale and rotate them in the objects properties panel by editing the values there, but when I press something like "R" on my keyboard to rotate, nothing happens.  For some reason, I can still grab objects via the "G" key, but when I try to scale and rotate using keyboard, nothing works.  I opened up a new blender window and everything worked fine in there, so I must have activated some weird setting somewhere.  Does anyone know how to fix this?

(blend file)
[image]

Comment: There's another possibility why this is happening: https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=6viFpjdOkjk (in case anyone else runs into a similar problem)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

uncheck "locations" here:

[image]

and i free tip:

don't ever just try out any shortcuts, if you are not sure what you are doing because nearly every shortcut does something in Blender - and something different n each area.